# Python Execution flow when Passing Functions as Arguments to other Functions

Tags: python, algorithm, function

Following is an example of "Passing a Function as Argument to other Function". I have struggled to understand  the execution flow of these statements.

```
 1  def plus_one(number):
 2      print(f" First: {number + 1}")
 3      return number + 1
 4
 5  def function_call(function):
 6      number_to_add = 5
 7      print(f" Second: {function(number_to_add)}")
 8      return function(number_to_add)
 9
10  function_call(plus_one)
```

Output of the above statements:

First: 6

Second: 6

First: 6

Which Function gets called first - "function_call" or "plus_one" ?

As per my understanding, function_call is called first with reference to plus_one fn as argument.

However, as per print output, plus_one function is called first. Please explain the logic behind this type of function call and if possible share any good doc with similar examples.

Comment: Add a print statement between lines 5 and 6 and see how this goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
print(f" Second: {function(number_to_add)}")
```

It calls `function` in order to get the return value to print. `function_call` is called first, but the call to `plus_one` is made before the `print` in `function_call`.

Comment: "..but the call to plus_one is made before the print in function_call." Which statement makes call to  plus_one or 'function' ?

Comment: The line I showed in my answer makes the call to `plus_one`, which has been passed in as the argument `function`.